# Delete Specific MySQL Database Entry

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to delete a specific entry in my MYSQL Database.

Database: PhotoID, IDCount, UserID.

This is my code for deleting a photo depending on the ID.

```
function delete($IdPhoto) {

$result = query("DELETE from photos WHERE IdPhoto='%d'", $IdPhoto);
if (!$result['error']) {
    // if no error occured, print out the JSON data of the 
    // fetched photo data
    print json_encode($result);
} else {
    //there was an error, print out to the iPhone app
    errorJson('Photo stream is broken');
}
}
```

This is paired with an iOS Application that grabs the current photos ID at all times. When a button is pressed, the delete function in the API will trigger. This doesn't seem to work though.

The following query works (specific ID):

```
    $result = query("DELETE from photos WHERE IdPhoto=10");
```

Any help would be appreciated. The goal is to delete the photo depending on the $IdPhoto we grab in the iOS Application.

Comment: What does the `query()` function return?

Comment: Nothing specific. Nothing at all, actually.

Comment: Then why are you checking to see if `$result['error']` exists, if `query()` doesn't return anything?

Comment: When you `echo($IdPhoto);` what do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = query("DELETE from photos WHERE IdPhoto={$IdPhoto}");
```

Answer (score 1):

did you tried this :

```
     $result = mysql_query("DELETE from photos WHERE IdPhoto='$IdPhoto'  ");
```

you should use `mysql_query`

Answer (score 1):

This

```
..IdPhoto='%d'
```

should be

```
..IdPhoto=%d
```

Since a `int` value shouldn't be surrounded by `quotes`

Answer (score 0):

The "=" will only compare two int values or double values. Make sure you are comparing the type int. Thus your delete function should pass an int, otherwise you might need a function like getIntvalue() to extract the int value.